# Why did we use back slash with a star here instead of just a star in the following code?

Tags: python, python-re

Why did we use back slash with a star here instead of just a star??

````
import re
text = 'The quick brown\nfox jumps*over the lazy dog.'
print(re.split('; |, |\*|\n',text))
```----> here in this line , and this code works well
````

Answer (score 1):

The backslash lets you escape special characters, in this case so that you can search for the `*` character.

Check out the documentation for `re` here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html